# Minimize collision risk for any hash function?

Tags: hash

What's some good advice on eliminating collisions when hashing things? I need a unique identifier for all my users, but I want them to be private. I'm thinking of using ODIN-1 (https://code.google.com/p/odinmobile/wiki/ODIN1), a sha1 of different device-specific identifiers; MAC for iOS, AndroidID for Android and DeviceUniqueId for Windows Phone.

However, what's the collision risk on those hashes? Would using another hashing function help? Another input? Platform-specific prefix? I really need every legitimate hash to be unique.

Let's ignore users who fake their hashes for now, since I cannot really do that much about them. Client side security is what it is.

Comment: You need a unique identifier. Why does it have to be derived from anything? Why not a UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Comparison of SHA functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) on Wikipedia. As the table shows, a *theoretical* collision attack with an estimated complexity of ~2^69 exists for SHA-1. See [Marc Stevens' presentation](http://2012.sharcs.org/slides/stevens.pdf) for reference.

Since you're concerned about collisions I recommend using SHA-2 instead. You can choose any of the variants, but I suggest you pick one that meets your security and performance requirements.

Comment: sha256? is that enough to eliminate collisions for a 48bit input?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, yes. Collision's don't occur with SHA-2. You could choose any of the variants, but I suggest you pick one that meets your security and performance requirements.

Comment: Well, hashes are only hashed client-side, once, so by that logic I should use the toughest hash I can come up with?

Comment: You are worrying about a made-up problem. Given a 48-bit input, you nor any of your users are ever going to experience a collision in any of the SHA-2 variants.